# Printing date twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print date twice, like so:

```
output
 -date: the date
 -someotherdate: the someotherdate
```

Well sort of, anyway the code below doesn't display:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.seconds')[0].innerHTML = secsleft % 60;
document.querySelectorAll('.minutes')[0].innerHTML = secsleft / 60 % 60;
```

whereas, this code does:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.seconds')[0].innerHTML = secsleft % 60;
```

While the rest of my code is unchanged. also secsleft = seconds left until the next epoch. so i assume because it changes size it could be a problem?

I don't know. AnyHelp would be awesome.

edit: the rest of the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .seconds {
            font-size: 5em;
        }
        .minutes {
            font-size: 4em;
        }
        .hours {
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        .days {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="seconds"/>
    <span class="minutes"/>
    <span class="hours"/>
    <span class="days"/>
    <article>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clock() {
            var time = new Date(),
            secsleft = (Math.pow(2, 31) - time.getTime() / 1000);
            document.querySelectorAll('.seconds')[0].innerHTML = secsleft % 60
        }
        setInterval(clock, 1000);
    </script>
    </article>
</body>
```

what doesnt work is this

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .seconds {
            font-size: 5em;
        }
        .minutes {
            font-size: 4em;
        }
        .hours {
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        .days {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="seconds"/>
    <span class="minutes"/>
    <span class="hours"/>
    <span class="days"/>
    <article>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clock() {
            var time = new Date(),
            secsleft = (Math.pow(2, 31) - time.getTime() / 1000);
            document.querySelectorAll('.seconds')[0].innerHTML = secsleft % 60;
            document.querySelectorAll('.minutes')[0].innerHTML = secsleft / 60 % 60;
            document.querySelectorAll('.hours')[0].innerHTML = secsleft 3600 % 24;
            document.querySelectorAll('.days')[0].innerHTML = secsleft % 86400;
        }
        setInterval(clock, 1000);
    </script>
    </article>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you are working and explain what you want to achieve !

Comment: can you also post your html?

Comment: pls try to showcase the working code in code snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3qytm2n/ - your code seems to work

Comment: @LIGHT actually your fiddle works because you're using <div> tags (correctly) - the OP is using <span> tags incorrectly.

Comment: @Derek, right -- he did not post any html codes before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're using `<span>` tags incorrectly. Span tags require a closing tag, not a / in the opening tag.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span:

> Tag omission: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

Replace:

```
<span class="seconds"/>
<span class="minutes"/>
<span class="hours"/>
<span class="days"/>
```

with

```
<span class="seconds"></span>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<span class="hours"></span>
<span class="days"></span>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, also it turned out i was missing some  () parentheses , but yea thank you kind sir